# Error in is.finite(x); need to add an additional line to a line chart (dplyr)

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

I have already attempted to search for this problem to no result. Have managed to reproduce the error below.

The problem: I'm trying to add a fourth line which represents the aggregate mean of all letters for each year. So far, I'm only able to generate the mean values for each letter. Everything runs fine until the last geom_line(), which is meant to generate the aggregate error. I've also tried inserting abline(). One other consideration is adding the "Mean" values under Letters so that they are generated anyway, but I believe there is a simpler method.

```
library(tidyverse)

Letters <- rep(c("A","B","C"),20)
Years <- rep(c(1990:1999),6)
Numbers <- runif(60, min = 0, max = 20) 

df <- data.frame(Letters, Years, Numbers) %>% 
        group_by(Letters,Years) %>% 
        summarise(Letter_Mean= mean(Numbers),.groups = 'drop')

meanallletters <- df %>% 
        group_by(Years) %>% 
        summarise(all_mean = mean(Numbers),.groups =  'drop') %>% 
        select(-Years)

lineplotsample <- df %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x=Years, y=Letter_Mean, color = Letters))

## this doesn't work
lineplotsample + geom_line() + geom_point() + geom_line(aes(Years, y= meanallletters))

## this works, but missing the line representing aggregate mean
lineplotsample + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would summarize the data and then bind it to the bottom of the original data, like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Letters <- rep(c("A","B","C"),20)
Years <- rep(c(1990:1999),6)
Numbers <- runif(60, min = 0, max = 20) 

df <- data.frame(Letters, Years, Numbers) %>% 
  group_by(Letters,Years) %>% 
  summarise(Letter_Mean= mean(Numbers),.groups = 'drop')

meanallletters <- df %>% 
  group_by(Years) %>% 
  summarise(Letters = "All", 
            Letter_Mean = mean(Letter_Mean))  %>% 
  bind_rows(df,.) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(Letters = factor(Letters, levels=c("A", "B", "C", "All")))

meanallletters %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Years, y=Letter_Mean, color = Letters)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Here's a more general way of specifying the levels.  It also deals with the situation wither `Letters` is initially a factor.

```r
library(tidyverse)

Letters <- rep(LETTERS,20)
Years <- rep(c(1990:1999),26)
Numbers <- runif(26*10, min = 0, max = 20) 

df <- data.frame(Letters, Years, Numbers) %>% 
  group_by(Letters,Years) %>% 
  summarise(Letter_Mean= mean(Numbers),.groups = 'drop')

meanallletters <- df %>% 
  mutate(Letters = as.character(Letters)) %>% 
  group_by(Years) %>% 
  summarise(Letters = "All", 
            Letter_Mean = mean(Letter_Mean))  %>% 
  bind_rows(df,.) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(Letters = factor(Letters, levels=c(levels(as.factor(df$Letters)), "All")))

meanallletters %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Years, y=Letter_Mean, color = Letters)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the response! One more question: the original data has hundreds of more levels than the sample provided. How would I adapt... ```levels=c("A", "B", "C", "All")```?

Comment: @withoutcake I updated the answer to include a more general solution to specifying the labels.